# How the numbers of Nazi deportees from France varied over time

Tags: data-request, france

I'd like to know how the rate of deportations of Jews from Nazi-occupied France varied over the course of the occupation.  Was it a steady flow?  Were there any clear trends?

Comment: Is this actually a data request? It sounds more like a question for [history.se]. If you actually want **data**, please say so (that includes adding the data-request tag) and [edit] your question according to https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like

Comment: @JanDoggen - I added the tag as you suggested.  I gave the part of the world previously.  I don't know how to answer the other questions in the answer you linked to.  If this still needs refining, can you point to what exactly I need to narrow down further?  I'm not picky about what sort of data, because I don't know enough to be picky. // Yes, I'm looking for data.  A graph would be lovely!  A table or some sentences would also be okay.  But it seems to me that the Nazis kept very good records, so I'm hopeful this data exists. But I'm willing to try History.  Would I delete this first?

Comment: It's fine here if you actually want data. If nothing turns up here you can still post on [History.se]